# Is there a way of getting the index of an active selection range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a code that will go through a list of numbers and interpolate a range of "new Xs" What I'm trying to do is instead of having to modify the code in order to loop through a different range of cells, I would like select the range of cells in the spreadsheet and then output the new data next to the existing data.

I was wondering if there was someway to index a selected range so I can use for my loops.

```
Private Sub Test_Click()
    Dim rng As Integer, num As Integer
    Dim xLower As Double, yLower As Double, xNew As Double
    Dim xHigher As Double, yHigher As Double, yNew As Double

    xNew = 0
    For num = 1 To 28
        xNew = xNew + 0.01
        xLower = 0
        yLower = 0

        xHigher = 1.26
        yHigher = 0

        For rng = 2 To 108
            If xNew - ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 1).Value < xNew - xLower And ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 1) < xNew Then
                xLower = ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 1).Value
                yLower = ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 3).Value

            ElseIf xNew + ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 1).Value < xNew + xHigher And ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 1) > xNew Then
                xHigher = ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 1).Value
                yHigher = ActiveSheet.Cells(rng, 3).Value
            End If
        Next rng

        yNew = (xNew - xLower) / (xHigher - xLower) * (yHigher - yLower) + yLower

        Cells(num, 7) = yNew
        Cells(num, 6) = xNew
    Next num

End Sub
```

Comment: Try something like `Dim rngData as range: set rngData = Range("A1:AB1000")`. You can copy the range easily then by something like this: `rngData.offset(0,rngdata.columns.count) = rngData.Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the selection as a range to loop through, and determine the location of the upper left cell in the range, such that:

```
dim ulRow as long, ulCol as long, selrng as range
ulRow = selection.row
ulCol = selection.column
Set selrng = application.selection
```

You can then loop with that info, or output relative to that range, e.g.,

```
for each cl in selrng
    if isempty(cl) then cells(ulRow,ulCol+1).value = "moo"
next cl
```

---

**Edit1:**

Adding in a way to find the last cell's row/col in case that's needed:

```
With selrng
    lr = .row + .rows.count - 1
    lc = .column + .columns.count - 1
end with
```

You can then loop like:

```
For i = ulRow to lr
    if cells(i,lc).value <> 0 then cells(i,lc+1).value = "moo"
next i
```

Comment: For sure, I'll try that and report as soon as I can. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to make it work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChrisRosas Please mark the "Check" to the left of the post if this answered your question so it can be marked appropriately in the question list.